# How do I remove divider between AppBarLayout and ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I am new to Stackoverflow so please be gentle to me.

I tried removing it by setting the elevation of some views to 0dp but it did not help. Please check the screenshot and help me find a solution to this problem.

Here is a screenshot of the App:

I have highlighted divider which I want to remove.

[image: Screenshot of the layout]

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.syedsauban.mjforums.launching">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="67dp"
                android:background="#F3F5F8"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/nav_menu_icon"
                        android:layout_width="28dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_icon" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="243dp"
                        android:layout_height="77dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nav_menu_icon"
                        android:src="@drawable/mjcet_forums_header" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <com.syedsauban.mjforums.CustomTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                style="@style/MyTabLayout"
                fontPath="font/weblysleekuil.ttf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tab"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#80c7ff"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#1D1D1D"
                app:tabTextColor="#95989A"
                tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="14dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/dp1"
                        app:civ_border_color="#80c7ff"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText

                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_margin="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:backgroundTint="#80c7ff"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:hint="Hey user, feel free to ask!"
                        android:paddingTop="6dp"
                        android:textColorHint="#666666"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:background="#dde2e4" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/bell" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemBackground="@color/secoond"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/first"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Use namespace `app` instead of `android`. Its `app:elevation`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :)